# update a record if value is not exist and cancel if exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here below my code and doesn't work

```
    $edituser = DB::table('users')
                    ->select('name','username')
                    ->where('name', $username)
                    ->first();
        
    if(is_null($edituser)) {
        $set = DB::table('users')->update(array('username' => $request->setnewusername));
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Username sudah tersedia');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Username berhasil diubah');
```

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not a proper way to explain what your actual problem is. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You are checking for a record and if it doesnt exist you are trying to update it? You can't update something that doesnt exist. Dont you mean insert?

Comment: "Update the record if it doesn't exist or cancel if it does exist" means to literally do nothing.  I'm afraid it's not clear what you're trying to do or what "doesn't work" about your attempt.

Comment: i don't mean insert but update

Comment: How can you update something that doesnt exist?

Comment: i want update a username for example 'Mark', i update with 'John' and if username 'John' not owned by others user,  Mark Username updated with 'John'

Comment: As people said in the above comments it would be better to make a better description of what is going wrong and what you expect. "My code doesnt work" is very broad and doesnt descripe what the problem is. So I would suggest to take a bit more time 'composing' your question next time :).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update a row that doesnt exist. You probably want to insert it. You use Laravel so I assume you have a user model:

```
$edituser = DB::table('users')
    ->select('name','username')
    ->where('name', $username)
    ->first();
    
if(is_null($edituser)) {
    //create a new user object, add the new name and save it to the database
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->setnewusername;
    $user->save();
} else {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Username sudah tersedia');
}
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Username berhasil diubah');
```

EDIT:
Based on your comments you can use the following, it checks if there is a user with newUsername (john), if there is none it will update the username of user mark to john. Note that it doesnt check if there is a user called Mark:

```
    $oldUsername = "mark";
    $newUsername = "john";


    if(is_null(DB::table('users')->select('name','username')->where('name', $newUsername)->first())) {
        $set = DB::table('users')->where('name', $oldUsername)->update(array('username' => $newUsername));
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Username sudah tersedia');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Username berhasil diubah');
```

Comment: thanks, but here i using Query Builder Not Eloquent

Comment: Ok I made an edit based on your comments